# C++ Recursive rabbit assignment

Tags: c++, recursion

It asks:

Modify the recursive rabbit function so that it is visually easy to follow the flow of execution. In stead of just adding "Enter" and "Leave" messages, indent the trace messages according to how "deep" the current recursive call is.

By exercising correctly adding white space(s) in the recursive rabbit function, better out understanding on how the recursion works.

This is what the program should display:

```
Enter rabbit: n = 4
   Enter rabbit: n = 3
      Enter rabbit: n = 2
      Leave rabbit: n = 2 value = 1
      Enter rabbit: n = 1
      Leave rabbit: n = 1 value = 1
   Leave rabbit: n = 3 value = 2
   Enter rabbit: n = 2
   Leave rabbit: n = 2 value = 1
Leave rabbit: n = 4 value = 3
```

I don't really have a clue to how to get the proper indentations or how to display the "leave rabbits" that have n greater than 2. So far my code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int rabbit(int);

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << rabbit(4) << endl;
    return 0;
}

int rabbit(int n)
{
cout << "Enter rabbit: n = " << n << endl;

if(n <=2)
{
    cout << "Leave rabbit: n = " << n << endl;
    return 1;
}
else
{
    return rabbit(n - 1) + rabbit(n - 2);
}
}
```

Can someone point me to the right direction? Thank you very much.

EDIT:

I have it somewhat close but it is still missing the ability to display "Leave rabbit: n = 3" and "Leave rabbit: n = 4."

Here is my new code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int rabbit(int, int);

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int months;

    cout << "How many months?" << endl << "Months ::: ";
    cin >> months;
    cout << rabbit(months, 0) << endl;
    return 0;
}
int rabbit(int n, int parameter)
{
    int value;

    for(int i = 0; i < parameter; i++)
    {
        cout << " ";
    }
    cout << "Enter rabbit: n = " << n << endl;

    if(n <=2)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < parameter; i++)
        {
            cout << " ";
        }
        value = 1;
        cout << "Leave rabbit: n = " << n << " value = " << value << endl;
        return value;
    }
    else
    {
        return rabbit(n - 1, parameter + 1) + rabbit(n - 2, parameter + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the hare function? :-)

Comment: Such a weak excuse! Shame on you ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll kick yourself, all you need to do is use the value variable for both cases.

```
int rabbit(int n, int parameter)
{
    int value;

    for(int i = 0; i < parameter; i++)
    {
        cout << " ";
    }
    cout << "Enter rabbit: n = " << n << endl;

    if(n <=2)
    {
        value = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        value = rabbit(n - 1, parameter + 1) + rabbit(n - 2, parameter + 1);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < parameter; i++)
    {
        cout << " ";
    }
    cout << "Leave rabbit: n = " << n << " value = " << value << endl;
    return value;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

On SO, we try not to give code solutions to assignments, and to your credit you are only asking for hints.

The key to solving any problem is to state it well.

If you look at the required output, you can see

1. The output from the first call is not indented.
2. The output from the next call is indented 3 spaces.
3. The output from the next call is indented 3 more spaces.

So: what is the relationship between the number of level of calls to `rabbit`, and the amount of indentation?

If there were more, deeper calls to `rabbit` we would expect a good solution to continue to work, giving greater levels of indentation.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I managed to make it closer to what it should look like. However, I'm not sure how I can get the "Leave rabbit: n = 3" and "Leave rabbit: n = 4" to display. Am I doing something wrong? I will edit my main post to have my most current code. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Just a hint, but try saving the value you're going to return, then print the leave line with it right before you return it.

Comment: Thank you very much. So far my program displays:                     Enter rabbit: n = 4
   Enter rabbit: n = 3
      Enter rabbit: n = 2
      Leave rabbit: n = 2 value = 1
      Enter rabbit: n = 1
      Leave rabbit: n = 1 value = 1
   Enter rabbit: n = 2
   Leave rabbit: n = 2 value = 1  , but I am missing "Leave rabbit: n = 3 value = 2" and "Leave rabbit: n = 4 value = 3", any clue for how to get those last two to display?

Comment: You're almost there.  There's 2 places that return a value in the rabbit function, they should both work the same way.